# adding ssl certi.p12 files in resource folder of android

Tags: android

I need to add .p12 file and keystore file in resource folder of android. This file is needed for ssl connection to server (not https).  How to add it? i have tried to add in any of folder in resouce folder but that is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is the problem? What error? You just need to copy the file as a raw resource in `/res/raw/mykey.p12`.

Comment: I need to open file mykey.p12.  I was doing by pasting in assets folder was not able to access it. I guess raw folder will help me.

Comment: If you put it in assets Android will try to compress it and that will effectively break the file.